# Does HTTP/2 prevent security vulnerabilites like CRLF injection?

Tags: http, software, web, http2, response-splitting

Which vulnerabilites does HTTP/2 prevent?

More specifically:

- Does it prevent HTTP request smuggling?
- Does it prevent HTTP response splitting / CRLF injection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TLS related security features in HTTP/2

The concrete security improvements mentioned in the [FAQ](https://http2.github.io/faq/#what-does-http2-do-to-improve-security) are related to TLS encryption: HTTP/2 MUST use at least TLS 1.2 and it support [SNI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066.html#section-3). Also, HTTP/2 introduces a [TLS 1.2 Cipher Suite Black List](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#BadCipherSuites) that implementations MAY treat as connection errors.

> [**What does HTTP/2 do to improve security?**](https://http2.github.io/faq/#what-does-http2-do-to-improve-security)
>
> HTTP/2 defines a profile of TLS that is required; this includes the
> version, a ciphersuite blacklist, and extensions used.
>
> See [the spec](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#TLSUsage) for details.
>
> There is also discussion of additional mechanisms, such as using TLS
> for HTTP:// URLs (so-called “opportunistic encryption”); see [RFC 8164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8164).

In addition to that, HTTP/2 provides secure compression features that enables you to have header compression while having TLS 1.2 compression disabled. From http2 explained:

> [**6.5.1. Compression is a tricky subject**](https://http2-explained.haxx.se/en/part6#6-5-1-compression-is-a-tricky-subject)
>
> HTTPS and SPDY compression were found to be vulnerable to the [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_%28security_exploit%29)
> and [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) attacks. By inserting known text into the stream and
> figuring out how that changes the output, an attacker can figure out
> what's being sent in an encrypted payload.
>
> Doing compression on dynamic content for a protocol - without becoming
> vulnerable to one of these attacks - requires some thought and careful
> consideration. This is what the HTTPbis team tried to do.
>
> Enter [HPACK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541.txt), Header Compression for HTTP/2, which – as the name
> suggests - is a compression format especially crafted for http2
> headers, and it is being specified in a separate internet draft. The
> new format, together with other counter-measures (such as a bit that
> asks intermediaries to not compress a specific header and optional
> padding of frames), should make it harder to exploit compression.

### Does HTTP/2 prevent HTTP request smuggling?

[HTTP request smuggling](https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling) isn't really a vulnerability in HTTP/1.1 protocol itself, but the existence of two different ways of specifying how the request ends ([`Content-Length`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) & [`Transfer-Encoding`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.1)) leaves room for bad HTTP proxy server chain implementations. In HTTP/2 there's only [one](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2#streams_messages_and_frames):

> In short, HTTP/2 breaks down the HTTP protocol communication into an
> exchange of binary-encoded frames, which are then mapped to messages
> that belong to a particular stream, all of which are multiplexed
> within a single TCP connection.

With these binary frames, the end of the *frame payload* (containing e.g. the request) is specified by the `Length (24)` field in the *frame header* ([RFC 7540, 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.1)), which makes it unambiguous. Therefore, the [HTTP request smuggling](https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling) article even mentions using HTTP/2 for back-end connections as one way to prevent these vulnerabilities:

> Some generic ways to prevent HTTP request smuggling vulnerabilities
> arising are as follows:
>
> - Disable reuse of back-end connections, so that each back-end request is sent over a separate network connection.
> - Use HTTP/2 for back-end connections, as this protocol prevents ambiguity about the boundaries between requests.
> - Use exactly the same web server software for the front-end and back-end servers, so that they agree about the boundaries between
>   requests.

### Does HTTP/2 prevent HTTP response splitting / CRLF injection?

*HTTP response splitting* is just an example of a *CRLF injection*. The way header block is treated (RFC 7540 [4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4), especially [4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.3)) leaves less room escaping from the header block simply using two CRLFs:

> Each header block is processed as a discrete unit.  Header blocks MUST
> be transmitted as a contiguous sequence of frames, with no interleaved
> frames of any other type or from any other stream.  The last frame in
> a sequence of HEADERS or CONTINUATION frames has the END_HEADERS flag
> set.  The last frame in a sequence of PUSH_PROMISE or CONTINUATION
> frames has the END_HEADERS flag set.  This allows a header block to be
> logically equivalent to a single frame.

A newline is also in general less significant as explained in Google's [Introduction to HTTP/2](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2):

> Unlike the newline delimited plaintext HTTP/1.x protocol, all HTTP/2
> communication is split into smaller messages and frames, each of which
> is encoded in binary format.

While the serialization of the *header list* can also help with other type of CRLF vulnerabilities like *HTTP Header Injection*s, it doesn't automatically prevent all possible CRLF vulnerabilities in the web application, as the web application could still treat `%0d%0a` in GET data, POST data, cookies or in any single header specially. To prevent that, e.g. [Netsparker Security Team recommends](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/crlf-http-header/):

> **How to Prevent CRLF / HTTP Header Injections in Web Applications**
>
> The best prevention technique is to not use users input directly
> inside response headers. If that is not possible, you should always
> use a function to encode the CRLF special characters. Another good web
> application security best practise is to update your programming
> language to a version that does not allow CR and LF to be injected
> inside functions that set HTTP headers.

Comment: So how can there be only one way of saying where something ends in HTTP/2? You need content-length for progress bars and transfer encoding for streaming data as it generates. Note that these are different use cases where different methods should be applied.

Comment: In HTTP/2 there's only a single method for all data streams, which is an exchange of binary-encoded frames. I've added some references that hopefully better explains how the request end is not specified like in these HTTP/1.1 headers, but in the *length* field of the *frame header*.