# CRLF in HTTP/2 header value

Tags: http, injection, header, http2

I am attempting to inject a carriage-return + newline in a HTTP request header value. My understanding is that this is possible with HTTP/2 and HTTP/3. However, when I send a request with Burp I get this error:

> RST_STREAM received with error code: 0x1 (Protocol error detected)

Does HTTP/2 support newlines in header values? Why do I get this error? Does Apache2 or PHP validate the header contents?

Comment: See also [Does HTTP/2 prevent security vulnerabilites like CRLF injection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235046/does-http-2-prevent-security-vulnerabilites-like-crlf-injection)

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 9113 HTTP/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9113.html) says that headers are a type of field:

> HTTP fields (Section 5 of [HTTP]) are conveyed by HTTP/2 in the HEADERS ...

And that newlines can be dangerous:

> Failure to validate fields can be exploited for request smuggling attacks.

And the following validation must be performed:

> A field name MUST NOT contain characters in the ranges 0x00-0x20, 0x41-0x5a, or 0x7f-0xff (all ranges inclusive). This specifically excludes all non-visible ASCII characters, ASCII SP (0x20), and uppercase characters ('A' to 'Z', ASCII 0x41 to 0x5a).

[Apache uses the nghttp2 library](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html), and that [indeed validates the header value](https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/blob/a65b0acd9e75697ffa22253bec887f6f58c77cab/lib/nghttp2_helper.c#L500) and [does not allow carriage return or linefeed characters](https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/blob/a65b0acd9e75697ffa22253bec887f6f58c77cab/lib/nghttp2_helper.c#L436-L437).

```
static const int VALID_HD_VALUE_CHARS[] = {
    ...
    0 /* BS   */, 1 /* HT   */, 0 /* LF   */, 0 /* VT   */,
    0 /* FF   */, 0 /* CR   */, 0 /* SO   */, 0 /* SI   */,
    ...
};

int nghttp2_check_header_value(const uint8_t *value, size_t len) {
  const uint8_t *last;
  for (last = value + len; value != last; ++value) {
    if (!VALID_HD_VALUE_CHARS[*value]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```